# CSS filter property changes height of inner DIV

Tags: css, side-effects, css-filters

I have noticed that setting the CSS `filter` property affects the height of a child `div` under certain circumstances.

My child `div` needs to be `position: fixed;` and `height: 100%;`
In combination with the `filter` property there is a strange side-effect.

Consider this code:

```css
.outer-div {
    filter: blur(5px);
}

.inner-div {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    
    min-height: 100px; /* Without this min-height, the DIV would be invisible with filter */ 

    /* Not relevant styling, just for making DIV visible */
    background-color: pink; 
    width: 200px;     
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, the height of the inner `div` is not `100%` anymore. Without the additional `min-height: 100px;` the inner `div` would be completely invisible when there is a `filter` property.

Toggling the `filter` property in browser's development tools clearly shows the weird phenomenon: Without `filter`, the height is `100%`, with the `filter` it is just `100px`.

Additional information:

- The value of the `filter` property doesn't seem to matter. Except `none`, all values I have tried affect the height.
- The phenomenon occurs in recent versions of both Chrome and Firefox.

Questions are now

- Why is this the case? Is this intended like this? Or is it a problem
  in the CSS standard? Or a bug in the implementations?
- Anyway: How can I solve this problem? The inner `div` needs the be `height: 100%`
  even with the `filter` property of the outer `div`.